# Adobe AIR - Eclipse like Preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adobe AIR - Custom Preloader with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917667/adobe-air-custom-preloader-with-image)

Folks,

I have designed an AIR application. I want to have a `Eclipse IDE` Like Preloader on it, so that when application starts, I can show that preloader ( consisting of `logo` + "`loading..`" + the `loading process`)

How to design preloader in Adobe AIR like that of `Eclipse IDE`  ?

Thanks

e.g

[image]

---

**PS : Please tell it using Flex3 and not Flex 4/4.5**