# Adobe AIR - Custom Splash Screen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adobe AIR - Custom Preloader with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917667/adobe-air-custom-preloader-with-image)

Folks,

I have a running Adobe AIR application on my desktop. But I want to add a splash screen to it.

I already saw some tutorials on this, but they were opening an new NativeWindow. I want to open existing application after splash screen.

How to do it ? Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: -1 since it is the same question as
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917667/adobe-air-custom-preloader-with-image and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927028/adobe-air-eclipse-like-preloader

Comment: Asking the same question three times is not okay, update your original question instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do something like that:

1) Set default windows not visible `nativeWindows.visible = false;`

2) Make a new window and use it as a splashscreen (set systemChrome to none and transparent to true)

3) After splashscreen simply set visible the original window.

**EDIT:**

Does your application use a SystemChrome or not?
I ask that because you can not change systemchrome after the windows is initialized and to add a spashscreen you usually do not use a systemchrome...

If your application do not use SystemChrome (`systemchrome = none` and `transparent = true`) simply create a new state as a `Start state`, show it and after X seconds or on `effect_end` animation simply changeState to normal state...