# Flex mobile - is it possible to have effects on splash screen?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

Flex mobile - is it possible to have effects on splash screen?

Like, fade effect on splashscreen image?

Thanks,
Raghu.

Comment: RIAStar provided a great answer to this [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917667/adobe-air-custom-preloader-with-image)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but it does not answer. I am able to get the splashscreen image, want the effect on this splashscreen.

Answer (score 0):

IOS doesn't support having effects on the splash screen.  You can only provide an image.  Hence, having effects on a splash screen will probably not work the way you want as Flex mobile has to work for multiple OSes.

You can get around it by having a static image for the original splash part, and then have a very similar image which has effects during your "initialization" phase.  I've used this before to create the same sort of experience.