# AS3 loading screen on iOS & android

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am building a book application in Flash Professional CS5.5 to be released on tablet devices and I am trying to understand the best structure for loading the application. For iOS devices I know I can include the default.png, but how can accomplish a similar task for Android? The book application is also going to be large as it includes a lot of assets and animations, is there a good way to show that this is loading on both platforms?

One thing I was trying was a loading screen where the main application was actually a loading system that would import the compiled SWF book, but further research shows that it won't work for iOS devices.

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Comment: Try looking at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7917667/516537

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end, I'm developing the main app itself for iOS and exporting that with the Default.png. Then the Android version is a smaller splashscreen/preloader app which will load the SWF version of the iOS app. Is this the correct way of doing it? Probably not, but it's what I've come up with after reading way too many articles that brush the concept.